# Kubernetes pod desc shows "connection refused" error

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am a Kubernetes newbie. I am running out ideas in solving the Pod status being stuck at `ContainerCreating`. I am working on a sample application from AWS (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html#eks-guestbook), the sample is very similar to the official sample (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/guestbook/).

Many thanks for anyone giving guidance in finding the root causes:

Why do I get conn refused error, what does port 50051 do? Thanks.

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

NAMESPACE     NAME                        READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
default       guestbook-8k9pp             0/1     ContainerCreating   0          15h
default       guestbook-b2n49             0/1     ContainerCreating   0          15h
default       guestbook-gtjnj             0/1     ContainerCreating   0          15h
default       redis-master-rhwnt          0/1     ContainerCreating   0          15h
default       redis-slave-b284x           0/1     ContainerCreating   0          15h
default       redis-slave-vnlj4           0/1     ContainerCreating   0          15h
kube-system   aws-node-jkfg8              0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    273        1d
kube-system   aws-node-lpvn9              0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    273        1d
kube-system   aws-node-nmwzn              0/1     Error               274        1d
kube-system   kube-dns-64b69465b4-ftlm6   0/3     ContainerCreating   0          4d
kube-system   kube-proxy-cxdj7            1/1     Running             0          1d
kube-system   kube-proxy-g2js4            1/1     Running             0          1d
kube-system   kube-proxy-rhq6v            1/1     Running             0          1d

$ kubectl describe pod guestbook-8k9pp

Name:           guestbook-8k9pp
Namespace:      default
Node:           ip-172-31-91-242.ec2.internal/172.31.91.242
Start Time:     Wed, 31 Oct 2018 04:59:11 -0800
Labels:         app=guestbook
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:             
Controlled By:  ReplicationController/guestbook
Containers:
  guestbook:
    Container ID:   
    Image:          k8s.gcr.io/guestbook:v3
    Image ID:       
    Port:           3000/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-jb75l (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True 
  Ready          False 
  PodScheduled   True 
Volumes:
  default-token-jb75l:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-jb75l
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                    From                                    Message
  ----     ------                  ----                   ----                                    -------
  Normal   SandboxChanged          11m (x19561 over 13h)  kubelet, ip-172-31-91-242.ec2.internal  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  74s (x19368 over 13h)  kubelet, ip-172-31-91-242.ec2.internal  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "guestbook-8k9pp_default" network: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: **desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:50051: connect: connection refused"**
```

Comment: Can you please install a pod network(calico/flannel) and try again https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network

Comment: Can you post the output for `kubectl -n kube-system logs aws-node-nmwzn`? I assume you are running EKS. What did you use to create your nodes?

Comment: Thanks @Rico. Yes, I run on EKS. I follow the steps (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html#eks-launch-workers) in creating the nodes. Pls find the output after running 'kubectl -n kube-system logs aws-node-nmwzn'. 

`=Starting installing AWS-CNI =
=Starting amazon-k8s-agent =
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: W1101 05:35:03.298184      10 client_config.go:533] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
Failed to communicate with K8S Server. Please check instance security groups or http proxy setting`

Comment: @hoque, thank you. My apology for not mentioning that I use EKS for the sample. So the cluster is created through AWS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kubernetes cluster that I created is on AWS EKS. The EKS cluster were created manually by me through the EKS console.

I have created a second cluster with official VPC sample for EKS cluster (https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation/2018-08-30/amazon-eks-vpc-sample.yaml), and it seems to be working now.

So the problem should be the VPC configurations. Once I figured out what actually went wrong, will post info here, thank you.

Comment: Ooops, just aware that I didn't update my latest findings.
I was following a AWS official writeup to setup VPC environment (forgot the link, it wasn't misleading but the steps involved are error prone), it was quite troublesome and I would recommend to follow below steps to create the needed environment throught CF.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html#vpc-create

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  Same error message, but much simpler set of Pods.
Using `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` it revealed that one particular node had CrashLoopBackOff.

I scaled-in my nodes, and then scaled-out again (effectively re-creating that node), and that problem seems to have gone away.